# Processing multiple files in Laravel 5.1 (as an API)

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

So this seems like a pretty basic thing but I can't find a lot of documentation online about what's going on....

I'm trying to run through a list of files using Laravel 5.1 and I can only return/process/see the first file. I'm using Postman to send the request to the API (so I know `multiple` is enabled in the `POST` request) and then iterating through that a few different ways:

```
public function files(Request $request)
{
    foreach($request->files as $file)
    {
        var_dump($file);
    }
}
```

even:

```
public function files()
{
    foreach($_FILES['files'] as $file)
    {
        var_dump($file);
    }
}
```

I'm always returning (or the object form if the `$request->files` method is used):

```
string 'Screen%20Shot%202015-10-23%20at%2010.07.23%20AM.png' (length=51)
string 'image/png' (length=9)
string '/tmp/phpZw1ALu' (length=14)
int 0
int 13687
```

Why is this happening? What can I do to see multiple files in Laravel 5.1's controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made a brand new page with the following code called `files.php` and it's now returning all three files (or however many I upload):

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<body>
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://lucolo.dev/files">
   <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
   <input type="submit" value="Upload">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The error was that I was had the `POST` request in Postman only accepting a parameter named `files` instead of `files[]`. Once that was changed, the code in my Laravel controller:

```
public function files(Request $request)
{
    foreach($request->files as $file)
    {
        var_dump($file);
    }
}
```

now returns:

```
array (size=3)
0 => 
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)[84]
  private 'test' => boolean false
  private 'originalName' => string 'Screen Shot 2015-10-23 at 10.07.23 AM.png' (length=41)
  private 'mimeType' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
  private 'size' => int 270504
  private 'error' => int 0
  private 'pathName' (SplFileInfo) => string '/tmp/php1M5ZJl' (length=14)
  private 'fileName' (SplFileInfo) => string 'php1M5ZJl' (length=9)
1 => 
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)[85]
  private 'test' => boolean false
  private 'originalName' => string 'Screen Shot 2015-10-26 at 7.28.59 PM.png' (length=40)
  private 'mimeType' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
  private 'size' => int 13687
  private 'error' => int 0
  private 'pathName' (SplFileInfo) => string '/tmp/phpE22ubf' (length=14)
  private 'fileName' (SplFileInfo) => string 'phpE22ubf' (length=9)
2 => 
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)[86]
  private 'test' => boolean false
  private 'originalName' => string 'Screen Shot 2015-10-27 at 2.50.58 PM.png' (length=40)
  private 'mimeType' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
  private 'size' => int 786350
  private 'error' => int 0
  private 'pathName' (SplFileInfo) => string '/tmp/phph8v0C8' (length=14)
  private 'fileName' (SplFileInfo) => string 'phph8v0C8' (length=9)
```

Hope that helps someone!