# Accessing file attributes with Symfony in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, symfony, filesystems, laravel-5.1

So I've figured out how to iterate through files uploaded to my API that is built with Laravel 5.1 - [Processing multiple files in Laravel 5.1 (as an API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458729/processing-multiple-files-in-laravel-5-1-as-an-api)

Now that I have that completed, I'm still not able to access the attributes of the files with Symfony as I iterate through them.

HTML page (for testing):

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://example.dev/files">
        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
public function files(Request $request)
{
    foreach($request->files as $file)
    {
        return var_dump($file->getClientOriginalName());
    }
}
```

Error: `Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on array`

If I just just `var_dump` the files with this controller method:

```
public function files(Request $request)
{
    foreach($request->files as $file)
    {
        return var_dump($file);
    }
}
```

... that returns:

```
array (size=3)
0 => 
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)[84]
  private 'test' => boolean false
  private 'originalName' => string 'Screen Shot 2015-10-23 at 10.07.23 AM.png' (length=41)
  private 'mimeType' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
  private 'size' => int 270504
  private 'error' => int 0
  private 'pathName' (SplFileInfo) => string '/tmp/phpzekUeL' (length=14)
  private 'fileName' (SplFileInfo) => string 'phpzekUeL' (length=9)
1 => 
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)[85]
  private 'test' => boolean false
  private 'originalName' => string 'Screen Shot 2015-10-26 at 7.28.59 PM.png' (length=40)
  private 'mimeType' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
  private 'size' => int 13687
  private 'error' => int 0
  private 'pathName' (SplFileInfo) => string '/tmp/phprYW7MZ' (length=14)
  private 'fileName' (SplFileInfo) => string 'phprYW7MZ' (length=9)
2 => 
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)[86]
  private 'test' => boolean false
  private 'originalName' => string 'Screen Shot 2015-10-27 at 2.50.58 PM.png' (length=40)
  private 'mimeType' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
  private 'size' => int 786350
  private 'error' => int 0
  private 'pathName' (SplFileInfo) => string '/tmp/phpLq3lle' (length=14)
  private 'fileName' (SplFileInfo) => string 'phpLq3lle' (length=9)
```

Why am I returning this Symfony error? How can I access the file attributes in the `foreach` loop with `getClientOriginalName()` and other functions outlined in http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: well, `var_dump($file)` is an array and that's what your error says: `Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on array`. Most likely your are using field for multiple files upload `name="file[]"`

Answer (score 0):

By using

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
```

You are asking the browser to send the `files` field as an array, so you end up getting an array which then includes an array of files. You can do one of two things:

1 - Use this instead:

```
<input type="file" name="files" multiple>
```

2 - Or change your code like this:

```
public function files(Request $request) {
    foreach($request->files as $files) {
        foreach($files as $file) {
            return var_dump($file->getClientOriginalName()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately removing the array doesn't work since HTML uses the array to insert multiple files into the `$_FILES` superglobal. If you don't include the array (ie `files[]`), you'll only return the first file's contents (since there is no array). As for your second option, that will work for a single file but not multiple. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Have you tested both suggestions or did you just decide they would not work?

Comment: I tested both and I suggest you try the same to see what I mean. Your second answer is still trying to get the property of an array, not a Symfony object, which is why it doesn't work. It'll return `Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on array`

Answer (score 0):

So I was finally able to figure it out by getting into the `$_FILES['files']` array (whose keys are attributes, not the files themselves, remember) in the `$request->files` object by using the `count` of the files' name attribute to form a `for` loop which incrementally returns the key of the array:

```
public function files(Request $request)
{
    $count = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        foreach($request->files as $file)
        {
            echo 'The name is '.$file[$i]->getClientOriginalName().'<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Not the most efficient way of doing it (due to time complexity) but, hey, the upload is the bottleneck here!

Hope that helps someone...